# How to return domain name from getServletContext().getContextPath()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have my application on production on some domain name ABC.com. In my code i am redirecting user to other page based upon on some action

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/time");
```

But by the above it get redirected to localhost:8080//time
but instead of this i want it to get redirected to ABC.com/time

How can i do this? A simple solution coming to my mind is that i should set some environment variable for production and instead of using

> request.getServletContext().getContextPath()

, i will use environment variable value i.e. ABC.com

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the domain under which your server can been reached, then the environment variable way is the only way that works all times (for example even if there is a proxy in front of your server...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this should work with the domain that you want, provided that the application is operating from said domain. Right now you are probably using a development environment on your localhost, which means the servlet is operating on `localhost:8080` and will also pass that back as it's path. When you deploy your application it should work.

If you need to redirect to the production version even though you are running in a development environment, you should hardcore the URL in a configuration variable of sorts. I prefer using `.conf` files and reading those at runtime since it allows you to alter their contents on the fly easily.

One minor thing that might cause issues is the double slashes. A path or URL will end in a slash so you don't have to append the second one. Simply doing `+ "time"` should be enough.